# Undefined reference to main error

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a Makefile of the [bitcount](https://github.com/t-crest/patmos-benchmarks/tree/master/MiBench/automotive/bitcount) benchmark application. The original Makefile works, but I want to change the Makefile for my needs. I want to create an object file first, and then use it to create .elf and .bin files.

```
bitcnts: ${FILE} Makefile
    gcc -static ${FILE} -O3 -o bitcnts
```

But I'm getting an error saying that `undefined reference to main'`:

```
/opt/riscv/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown elf/4.9.2/../../../../riscv64-unknown-
elf/lib/soft-float/32/crt0.o: 
In function `.L0 ': (.text+0x40): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'prog.elf' failed
make[1]: *** [prog.elf] Error 1
```

The attempted Makefile looks like this:

```
CROSS=riscv64-unknown-elf-
CC=$(CROSS)gcc    
LD=$(CROSS)g++
OBJCOPY=$(CROSS)objcopy
LIB_O=$(LIB)mutex.o $(LIB)wrap_malloc.o

CFLAGS_SYS=-m32 -msoft-float
LDFLAGS_SYS=-m32 -msoft-float -T$(LDFILE) -Wl,--wrap,malloc -Wl,--wrap,free -Wl,
--wrap,calloc -Wl,--wrap,realloc -Wl,--wrap,_malloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_free_r -Wl,
--wrap,_calloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_realloc_r

CFLAGS=-g $(CFLAGS_SYS) -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wall -I$(LIB) -I./
LDFLAGS=-g $(LDFLAGS_SYS)


FILE = bitcnt_1.c bitcnt_2.c bitcnt_3.c bitcnt_4.c bitcnts.c bitfiles.c 
bitstrng.c bstr_i.c

MAIN = bitcnts

.PHONY : all
all: prog.elf

prog.bin : prog.elf
   @${OBJCOPY} -R .uncached -R .tileram -O binary $< $@

prog.elf : $(MAIN).o $(LIB_O)
   @${LD} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

$(MAIN).o : $(FILE)
   @${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: build
build: all
```

And then to build:

```
# Build
.PHONY: bitcount-build
bitcount-build:
  @make -C $(MIBENCH)/automotive/bitcount build
# Run
.PHONY: bitcount-run
bitcount-run:
  @make -C $(MIBENCH)/automotive/bitcount run
```

Comment: perhaps none of the files you listed in the Makefile have a main function

Comment: Please show the actual command that `make` tried to run.  It may help to remove the `@` symbol from the rule.

Comment: @bruceg `bitcnts.c` has a main function.

Comment: @BenVoigt I added the commands for make.

Comment: No, I mean the command that `make` expanded `@${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@` into and ran.

Comment: Why are you making a dependence on all `FILE`s but using only `$<`? I'd try putting `$(FILE)` instead of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule

```
$(MAIN).o : $(FILE)
   @${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

expands into

```
bitcnts.o: bitcnt_1.c bitcnt_2.c bitcnt_3.c bitcnt_4.c bitcnts.c bitfiles.c bitstrng.c bstr_i.c
    ...-gcc [all the flags] -c bitcnt_1.c -o bitcnts.o
                               ^^^^^^^^^^ $< is this only
```

The other files, `bitcnt_2.c`, `bitcnt_3.c`, `bitcnt_4.c`, `bitcnts.c`, `bitfiles.c`, `bitstrng.c`, `bstr_i.c`, are watched for modifications but never compiler into the object and if your `main()` was in `bitcnts.c`, `bitcnts.o` will not contain it.

Actually, what you want to do can not be done just as easy (sorry for the previous version of my answer that was wrong). [One object file comes from one translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (basically from one C file). So you'll have to make 8 of them. Luckily Makefiles make that not too hard either using [static patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage):

```
OBJECTS = $(FILE:%.c=%.o)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    @${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

prog.elf : $(OBJECTS) $(LIB_O)
    @${LD} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}
```

Comment: I get this error: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Comment: @Mrchacha Sorry about that, it was my mistake earlier. Try this.